# Implement User.updatePhoneNumber

Tags: react-native-firebase

When reading through the docs I found that `updatePhoneNumber` is not implemented in react-native-firebase.

> The following methods are not supported in RNFirebase as they cannot work in the React Native environment or have a different implementation.

So how would I implement this specific method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Salakar` from the `react-native-firebase` team here - support for `updatePhoneNumber` is landing in the upcoming v5.0.0 release of `react-native-firebase`.

If you need this sooner and are ok with using a release candidate version of the library then there should be another v5 RC version published by the end of next week with this change included (v5.0.0-rc2) - keep an eye out on discord for an announcement or the releases page on GitHub.